# If PHPMailer fails, fallback to native PHP mail function

Tags: php, phpmailer

The [PHPMailer documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) in its various use case examples suggests that the final part of the code -- the send -- should display an error message if it fails:

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

What I would prefer to do in case of failure is provide a fallback to the native PHP mail() function. The benefit is that an e-mail will still send to me, and it can carry the notice that PHPMailer failed.

```
// If PHPMailer code library fails (for whatever reason), fallback to mail()
if (!mail->send()) {

     //  just an example
     $to      = 'me@mydomain.com';
     $subject = 'You have a new e-mail subscriber + ERROR REPORT';
     $message = 'user input data and error description here';
     mail($to, $subject, $message);

} else {

     // other settings defined earlier in script
     $mail->Subject = 'You have a new e-mail subscriber';
     $mail->Body = $message;    
     $mail->send();

}
```

I'm hesitant to use the PHPMailer language as the `IF` expression, as a complete fallback to PHP seems more secure and reliable to me. Is there a better way to write this?

EDIT: Based on a comment below here's a bit more clarification. PHPMailer by default uses `mail()`. So this question won't apply in the default scenario. However, my implementations always use custom SMTP settings (e.g. smtp.google.com) which require a username and password. My question concerns the possibility that something goes wrong with the custom mail server, the username or the password. Hence, I am looking for a fallback solution beyond the simple error message on-screen.

Comment: By using the `mail->send()` in the `if` statement, then again in your `else` body, you may be sending the email twice on success?

Comment: Yes, I agree. The code I posted was mostly for illustration purposes. I'm thinking there's got to be a better way to do this.

Comment: This question makes no sense at all. By default PHPMailer calls `mail()` itself, so this isn't a fallback at all. If you're using the SMTP transport and that fails, you could call `isMail()` and call `send()` again and it would do exactly what your chosen answer does, but without the myriad problems associated with calling `mail()` yourself.

Comment: @Synchro, I'm not sure your comment is accurate. _"By default PHPMailer calls `mail()` itself"_ ... Yes. That is correct. And if I was using the default setting I wouldn't need to ask this question. However, everywhere I use PHPMailer I use custom SMTP settings (e.g. smtp.google.com) which require a username and password. My question concerns the possibility that something goes wrong with the custom mail server, the username or the password. Hence, I was looking for a fallback solution beyond a simple error message on-screen.

Comment: Sure, that's why I posted my answer that does exactly that, using PHPMailer.

Comment: @Synchro, I have updated the question based on your comments. Thanks.

Comment: It still doesn't make much sense. You're effectively saying that if mail() doesn't work, you want to fall back to using mail(). Just because you have set host, username etc for PHPMailer, it doesn't mean that any of those settings will be used. Since ultimately PHPMailer calls mail(), all you're saying is that you prefer not to do any error checking, which doesn't invoke feelings of sympathy!

Comment: It appears you are saying the SMTP transport also uses `mail()`. The whole idea here is that if the SMTP custom setting (which I believe sends the data through the custom server -- not using `mail()` -- fails, then fallback to `mail()`.

Comment: And with regard to error checking, of course it matters, and my question seeks a more robust solution: instead of a simple error message on screen (which only the site visitor sees), the system will send me an e-mail -- guaranteed -- with the user input and the error message.

Comment: I am not saying the SMTP transport uses `mail()`, I'm saying that the SMTP settings in PHPMailer will be ignored if you call `$mail->isMail()` and it will send using `mail()` instead, which is what my answer shows. This is what I meant about error checking - you can either have PHPMailer do all your error checking for you, or do none at all, like the chosen answer does. Bear in mind that if PHPMailer fails to send, then `mail()` is likely to fail too, for the same reason, whatever that may be. There is no guarantee `mail()` will succeed where PHPMailer does not because they do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first make the assignments for PHPMailer. Within the if statement, `!$mail->send()` part already tries to send the mail. So within your `else` statement, actually you send the mail again with PHPMailer. You can just use as below. It will try to send mail with PHPMailer, if fails, it will use PHP's mail function.

```
 $mail->Subject = 'You have a new e-mail subscriber';
 $mail->Body = $message;    
 if (!$mail->send()) { 
     $to      = 'me@mydomain.com';
     $subject = 'You have a new e-mail subscriber + ERROR REPORT';
     $message = 'user input data and error description here';
     mail($to, $subject, $message);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment, here's how you would fall back from using the SMTP transport to using the `mail()` transport within PHPMailer:

```
...
$mail->isSMTP();
if (!$mail->send()) {
    //Fall back to using mail()
    $mail->isMail();
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message failed to send';
    } else {
        echo 'Message sent via mail()';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Message sent via SMTP';
}
```